# In JPA does an entity have access to the Embedded of its Embedded object?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Does an entity have access to an `Embedded` of its `Embedded` object? E.g.:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    @Embedded
    protected AddressResearchChangeActivity activity;
}

public class ClaimantAddress {
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
}
```

So can `ClaimantAddress` access the `AddressResearchChangeActivity`?

And when we save `ClaimantAddress` will the data of `AddressResearchChangeActivity` also be saved?

Answer (score 3):

Embedded objects are just a way to group several fields inside an entity. When you save an entity, everything is saved in the entity, including all the embedded objects (and their sub-embedded objects).